# Firebase: Confusion regarding batched writes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-dom

I'm having some difficulties with firebase batched write in my React app.

Using the following async function:

```
export const addCollectionAndDocuments = async (collectionKey, objectsToAdd) => {
    const collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionKey);

    const batch = firestore.batch();
    objectsToAdd.forEach(obj => {
        const newDocRef = collectionRef.doc();
        batch.set(newDocRef, obj);
    });

    return await batch.commit();
}
```

If I call the function in my app in a way similar to this:

```
var list = [
    { date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    { date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];

addCollectionAndDocuments('foo-collection', list)
    .then((value) => {
        console.log('then ' + value);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        console.log('catch', e);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        console.log('finally');
    });
```

This doesn't do anything, **unless** I modify/invalidate my firebase API key in my firebase config object (i.e., in my app, modify the API key so that it doesn't correspond to my actual firebase API key) and then run the code. In that case, it works just fine, which puzzles me.

I am initializing firebase in a way similar to this:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

I have tried this numerous times, but nothing happens until I invalidate my firebase API key. Until then, I don't even reach any of the 'then', 'catch' nor the 'finally' methods in my promise.

The code above is in a simple create-react-app and I am currently running it on the 'react-scripts start' development server.

If I instead run batched write code in a static html document, it works completely as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "x",
    authDomain: "x",
    databaseURL: "x",
    projectId: "x",
    storageBucket: "x",
    messagingSenderId: "x",
    appId: "x"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  function myFunction() {
    // Get a new write batch
    const firestore = firebase.firestore();
    var batch = firestore.batch();

    // Set the value of 'NYC'
    var nycRef = firestore.collection("cities").doc("NYC");
    batch.set(nycRef, {name: "New York City"});

    // Commit the batch
    batch.commit().then(() => {
        console.log('done');
    });
}
</script>

<p>run stuff</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run batched write</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what this is about?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "invalidate my Firebase API key".

Comment: In my app, modify it so that it doesn't correspond to my actual firebase API key

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about that?  No one should ever have any reason to be messing with configurations like this.

Comment: Sure - I have also added a snippet showing how I initialize firebase

Comment: do you have an error message, or the logs generated?